# Set multiple UILabels vertically with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have build a UITableViewCell with Autolayout:

[image]

As you can see i put a ContainerView inside the ContentView with a little padding on the left and the right Side and than i put a lot of UILabels inside the ContainerView and one UIView.

All Headline Labels have set `numberOfLines` to 1

All Headlines will have only one Word as Text, so one Line should be enough!

All Headlines have 4 Constraints (Top,Left,Right,Bottom)

All Sublines Labels have set `numberOfLines` to 0

I get a unknown Length of Strings for every Subline, so it should resize so that the Text fit inside every Subline

All Sublines have 4 Constraints (Top,Left,Right,Bottom)

The UIView have always the same height so i set a fixed Height

The ContainerView have also four Constraint (Top,Right,Left,Bottom)

When i run my Application most of the Label gets shown correct but some Labels get completeley removed from the Cell. It looks like the whole Cell is not high enough to show all UILabels correctley, so some Labels get deleted. What could be the Problem?

Comment: Do you use AutoLayout to resize the tableView cell size?

Comment: You said it yourself, it appears that your cell isn't high enough ; have you tried increasing the height ? I'd say, for example, triple the height to have ridiculous cells, but a clear idea of where your labels are, and this could help you investigate/react.
Also, you could use the view herarchy inspector to see if the labels are below the cell

Comment: Also, couldn't you trade your approach of "a million labels in one cell" with "two labels per cell, and a million cells in one section" ? That approach looks more dynamic and the tableview would handle all the work for you ; you'd just have to change how you layout your view but that shouldn't be too much work

Comment: I also would like to do this, but i have to put all the Labels in one Cell ;) What do you mean by increasing the Height? In interface builder everything looks good and the size is also correct and while runtime the Autolayout should resize the whole Cell for me,isn't it?